# IdentityServer4 - Using External Authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, openid, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am trying to implement an Authorization server using IdentityServer4, using the Hybrid Flow.
let's say url is : auth.company.com

To authenticate users, the company uses a simple .NET MVC login/password form.
url : client.company.com/login.html

My question is : how can i plug the authentication system into the IdentityServer4 ?

I've tried adding this :

**Startup.cs / ConfigureServices()**

```
services.AddIdentityServer(SetupIdentityServer)
 private static void SetupIdentityServer(IdentityServerOptions options)
        {
            options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = @"client.company.com/login.html";
            options.UserInteraction.LoginReturnUrlParameter = "referrer";

        }
```

But it resulted in too many redirections error between auth server and authentication server
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just replied to another question very similar to this so this is a shameless copy and paste of that:

This will not work as the identity server needs to issue its own cookie once authentication has taken place. This cookie is what allows the authorise endpoint to know who is signed in.

The intention of this model is that authentication takes place on the IDP or it’s negotiated with an external provider via a suitable protocol. Therefore the appropriate approach in this case is to move the login UI into your identity server application. It’s entirely up to you exactly how that is done and where it gets it’s data from but it must be your identityserver4 that issues the cookie.